# How can i use an existing value from another model in Odoo?

Tags: python, model, odoo, field

i have a field called

```
yearly_holidays_ids = fields.One2many('hr.employee.yearly.holidays', 'employee_id')
```

in `'hr.employee'`  model

i would need this `(remaining_count = fields.Integer(compute='_remaining', store=True)`
integer field  data  in  the  `'hr.employee.yearly.holidays'` model, and  use  it  in  `'hr.employee'`  model,  how  do  i  do  it,  a  compute  field?

Thanks for help!

Comment: could you share code showing your model structure. ie, both models and their fields

Answer (score 0):

Start bt looking to a relation between those models `hr.employee` and `hr.employee.yearly.holidays`. And as per your question, the relation here is an one2many relation defined inside your `hr.employee` model and named `yearly_holidays_ids`

Since it is an one2many relation `yearly_holidays_ids` so it is not a one element or object but instead a set of elements linked to the employee, so you have to loop over this set.

To access the `yearly_holidays_ids` field and loop over it, this might depends on the function and API call you are performing, but it might be something similar to `self.yearly_holidays_ids`